# React native Lottie animations onAnimationFinish doesn't work on ios

Tags: javascript, react-native, lottie

Hello I am using lottie animations for the first time in react native , I got to a point where the lottie animation playes and when the animation finish with onAnimationFinish it should navigate to a new page, it works perfectly on android but when I test it on ios the animation plays and the when the animation ends it leaves you on the same page and and the onAnimationFinish didn't trigger.

```
    const progress = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
     
    const handleLikeAnimation = () => {
      Animated.timing(progress, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 3000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };
```

```
        <View style={{justifyContent:'center', width, height}}>
     <LottieView  style={{width:50, height:100, alignSelf:'center'}} progress={progress} source={require('../assets/lottie/loaderlottie.json')} autoPlay loop={false}  onAnimationFinish={() => navigation.navigate("Leaderboard" , currentcomp)}></LottieView> 
       </View>
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem like enough to reproduce your issue, can you include the relevant code please?

Answer (score 0):

I added some attributes in it and started working:

```
autoPlay
loop
speed={1}
```

Especially `speed={1}` made it work.

Hope it works for you too :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this solution didn't work, in fact, it shouldn't even work. The docs state that the onAnimationFinish event isn't called when the animation is looped

Comment: @rybur Right my problem persists too , I don't know what's wrong